# Syslinux "Missing OS" after expanding to the left the partition with /boot

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, gparted, syslinux

I have a GPT partitioned drive.
Its a bit of a mess so I was starting to sort everything out.

`/dev/sda2` is an ArchLinux install and the location of `/boot` with syslinux being used.

`/dev/sda1` is a ubuntu install.

I plan soon to complete do away with the ubuntu partition but for now just make it smaller and the increased `/dev/sda2` in size by moving the start of it up to the end of the ubuntu partition.

However now syslinux will not start and the computer just comes up with a missing os error.

Acording to gparted `/dev/sda2` does still have the boot flag.

I have used a live CD to check with gparted If the partitions are still ok and everything does seem fine it just cant boot.

What should I do to get syslinux booting again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169843) is you.  So, if so, since you are on Arch Linux have you tried to reinstall the Syslinux bootloader?

(As root):
`syslinux-install_update -i -a -m`

`syslinux-install_update` script to automatically install the bootloader (`-i`), mark the partition active by setting the boot flag (`-a`), and install the MBR boot code (`-m`)

Since you have a GPT partitioning scheme ensure `gptfdisk` is installed if not already or the above root command will fail.

Ensure that `/boot/syslinux/syslinux.cfg` actually points to the right partitions (e.g. /dev/sda2) for your specific set-up.

Comment: Yes that is me, although I currently am not in Arch, I assume I could just boot the live CD, mount `/dev/sda2` and `arch-chroot` into it?

Comment: Yes, arch-chroot should do it.  When I first installed my own system I forgot to mark the boot partition so I had to do that too: boot off the CD and arch-chroot into the drive after mounting the partitions and then installing the bootloader.  It works, that's what you should try.